# Jekyll include markdown file not rendering html

Tags: html, include, markdown, jekyll

I have a Jekyll site with an include file. Within that include file I am trying to include another file:

```html
<div class="api-doc api-off api-definition" id="debugging">{% include_relative _apiDocs/debugging.md %}</div>
```

but this displays the markdown as a string:

````
--- title: API Reference | Debugging --- #### Debugging Turn on debugging: ```Javascript pbjs.setConfig({ debug: true }); ```
````

Is there a way to get this to render as HTML?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Kramdown as your processor, you can handle this by adding the `markdown="1"` attribute to the parent div:

```html
<div class="api-doc api-off api-definition" id="debugging" markdown="1">{% include_relative _apiDocs/debugging.md %}</div>
```

If not, you can apply a filter on the included Markdown to convert it to HTML ([see the Jekyll docs on the *markdownify* filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/)):

```html
{%- capture debugging-doc -%}{% include_relative _apiDocs/debugging.md %}{%- endcapture -%}
<div class="api-doc api-off api-definition" id="debugging">{{ debugging-doc | markdownify }}</div>
```